# When response is embed it only returns 1 set answer out of a random selection Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a very simple discord.js bot, and I have a command for when someone types `/mahdi` it returns a random response out of a list that I made. When it returned in a normal message, it would pick a random one each time, but then I made it so it sends in an embed, and now it picks one and sends that all the time, until I take the bot offline which then picks another one to send all the time when it goes back online.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Code to randomly select a phrase from a list:

```
const mahdis = ['phrase1', 'phrase2', 'phrase3', 'phrase4', 'phrase5', 'phrase6', 'phrase7', 'phrase8'];
const mahdi = Math.floor(Math.random() * mahdis.length);
```

Code to send it as an embed:

```
const mahdiEmbed = {
    color: 'c0ffee',
    author: {
        name: 'supreme sauce 3.0',
        icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/733259381898215495/739b2c90fbfab048abb236b0e89770be.webp?size=256',
    },
    fields: [
        {
            name: mahdis[mahdi],
            value: '- mahdi',
        },
    ],
    footer: {
        text: 'supreme sauce 3.0 --- developed by ed#6969',
        icon_url: 'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/693559044329177151/733614790567788574/kirbmelon.gif',
    },
};

client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content === '/mahdi') {
        message.channel.send({ embed: mahdiEmbed });
    }
});
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined `mahdi` (which should be random every message) outside of your message event, it will be randomized only once, and that's when your bot starts.

If you put it in your message event, it will be randomized every new message. And that's what you want.

```js
const mahdis = ['phrase1', 'phrase2', 'phrase3', 'phrase4', 'phrase5', 'phrase6', 'phrase7', 'phrase8'];

client.on("message", message => {
    const mahdi = Math.floor(Math.random() * mahdis.length);
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "mahdi") {
        const mahdiEmbed = {
            color: 'c0ffee',
            author: {
                name: 'supreme sauce 3.0',
                icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/733259381898215495/739b2c90fbfab048abb236b0e89770be.webp?size=256',
            },
            fields: [
                {
                    name: mahdis[mahdi],
                    value: '- mahdi',
                },
            ],
            footer: {
                text: 'supreme sauce 3.0 --- developed by ed#6969',
                icon_url: 'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/693559044329177151/733614790567788574/kirbmelon.gif',
            },
        };
        message.channel.send({embed: mahdiEmbed});
    }
})
```